# asp.net linkbutton client-side problem

Tags: asp.net, linkbutton

I have this linkbutton with post-back disabled ... I should have done it with an html control but just did it that way .. It is toggling a language bar on top (marara.com.tr - language link)
It needs to be clicked twice in order to get the div to fade-in. I can correct the problem but just want to know why it behaves like that. .. in the first click it adds a # sign to the address bar then on the second click it does what it is supposed to.. any leads?

thanx in advance

Emre

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  It depends on the browser you are using (This occurred when I was using Firefox but not when I was testing in IE6).  It seemed like the browser looks at the URL and sees that nothing has changed (except the #...) so it doesn't reload the URL, causing the #... not to register.  You can trick it into thinking the query string has changed by adding a '&' before the '#' so that you add &#... to the URL.